# wsprintf() crashes application but is successful

Tags: c++, concatenation, wchar-t

Why on the following code [`wsprintf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-wsprintfa) crashes application even if the operation was successful?

```
#include "Shlwapi.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment( lib, "shlwapi.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);

    wchar_t* filepart = PathFindFileName(buffer);
    PathRemoveExtension(filepart);

    PWSTR path = NULL;
    HRESULT hres = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Downloads, 0, NULL, &path);

    wsprintf(path, TEXT("%s\\%s.bz2"), path, filepart);

    wcout << path << endl << endl;

    if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
        CoTaskMemFree(path);

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write the output of `wsprintf()` to a memory buffer that is not large enough to hold the output.  You are using the buffer that is allocated by `SHGetKnownFolderPath()`, which is large enough to hold only the path it returns.  You can't append to that buffer as-is, you wold have to reallocate it with [`CoTaskMemRealloc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cotaskmemrealloc) to make it larger, eg:

```cpp
#include "Shlwapi.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment( lib, "shlwapi.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);

    wchar_t* filepart = PathFindFileName(buffer);
    PathRemoveExtension(filepart);

    PWSTR path = NULL;
    HRESULT hres = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Downloads, 0, NULL, &path);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
    {
        int len = lstrlenW(path);
        PWSTR newpath = (PWSTR) CoTaskMemRealloc(path, len + lstrlenW(filepart) + 6);
        if (newpath)
        {
            path = newpath;
            wsprintfW(path+len, TEXT("\\%s.bz2"), filepart);
            wcout << path << endl << endl;
        }
        else
            wcout << L"CoTaskMemRealloc failed" << endl << endl;

        CoTaskMemFree(path);
    }
    else
        wcout << L"SHGetKnownFolderPath failed. Error " << (int)hres << endl << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Though really, you should just allocate your own buffer instead and copy the various substrings into it, eg:

```cpp
#include "Shlwapi.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment( lib, "shlwapi.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);

    wchar_t* filepart = PathFindFileNameW(buffer);
    PathRemoveExtensionW(filepart);

    PWSTR path = NULL;
    HRESULT hres = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Downloads, 0, NULL, &path);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
    {
        wchar_t fullPath = new wchar_t[lstrlenW(path) + lstrlenW(filepart) + 6];
        wsprintfW(fullPath, L"%s\\%s.bz2", path, filepart);

        wcout << fullPath << endl << endl;

        delete[] fullPath;
        CoTaskMemFree(path);
    }
    else
        wcout << L"SHGetKnownFolderPath failed. Error " << (int)hres << endl << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Or, you could just get rid of `wsprintf()` and print the various substrings directly to `std::wcout` instead, eg:

```cpp
#include "Shlwapi.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment( lib, "shlwapi.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);

    wchar_t* filepart = PathFindFileNameW(buffer);
    PathRemoveExtensionW(filepart);

    PWSTR path = NULL;
    HRESULT hres = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Downloads, 0, NULL, &path);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
    {
        wcout << path << L"\\" << filepart << L".bz2" << endl << endl;
        CoTaskMemFree(path);
    }
    else
        wcout << L"SHGetKnownFolderPath failed. Error " << (int)hres << endl << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

If you need a formatted variable, use a `std::wstring`, such as from `std::wostringstream`, eg:

```cpp
#include "Shlwapi.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#pragma comment( lib, "shlwapi.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);

    wchar_t* filepart = PathFindFileNameW(buffer);
    PathRemoveExtensionW(filepart);

    PWSTR path = NULL;
    HRESULT hres = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Downloads, 0, NULL, &path);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
    {
        wostringstream oss;

        oss << path << L"\\" << filepart << L".bz2";
        CoTaskMemFree(path);
        
        wstring fullPath = oss.str();
        wcout << fullPath << endl << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
#include "Shlwapi.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment( lib, "shlwapi.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);

    wchar_t* filepart = PathFindFileNameW(buffer);
    PathRemoveExtensionW(filepart);

    PWSTR path = NULL;
    HRESULT hres = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Downloads, 0, NULL, &path);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
    {
        wstring fullPath;
        fullPath.reserve(lstrlenW(path) + lstrlenW(filepart) + 5);

        fullPath += path;
        fullPath += L"\\";
        fullPath += filepart;
        fullPath += L".bz2";

        CoTaskMemFree(path);
        
        wcout << fullPath << endl << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The pointer returned by [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) does not have extra space for you to append characters to. You need to allocate your own buffer to write the full file path to.

Incidentally, doing a `sprintf` type operation into a buffer and passing that buffer as a parameter as one of the source operands is Undefined Behavior. Rather than using `wsprintf`, you should use one of the alternative functions mentioned in the documentation page you link to.

Answer (score 2):

`SHGetKnownFolderPath` allocates only the amount of memory the `SHGetKnownFolderPath` requires. But in this line

```
wsprintf(path, TEXT("%s\\%s.bz2"), path, filepart);
```

You are extending the string length, accessing unallocated memory, causing undefined behavior. If you remove this line, your application will not crash on `CoTaskMemFree`.

Comment: "*If you use your `buffer` variable, your code will work just fine:*" - no, because `filepart` points inside of `buffer`, and passing the same buffer as both input and output is *undefined behavior*. You would have to copy the contents of the `filepart` substring to a separate buffer first.